# CakePHP: One to One relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, database-relations

I'm a bit confused in how CakePHP does it's database relationship.

For a hasOne relationship, according to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone):

"User hasOne Profile"

`User hasOne Profile` -> `profiles.user_id`

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
    [Profile] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [user_id] => 121
            [skill] => Baking Cakes
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
)
```

But isn't this a one to many relation?

For example (I made these table to illustrate my confusion):

[image]

[image]

In this case then there are 2 profiles belonging to the same user. Doesn't this mean a user hasMany profile?

Would it make more sense if "User hasOne Profile" is

[image]

[image]

So then this would be "User hasOne Profile" but "Profile hasMany User"?

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: From where are you getting those table images?

Comment: I made it myself, just to illustrate my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example at the documentation when its said that a user has one profile it means that a user can only have one profile.

Therefor is a one to one relationship. You can choose where you prefer to have the foreign key, and they preferred to use it on the `profile` table.

Your images are wrong. In your case it would be a one to many. Which is a `hasMany` + `belongsTo`.
They just decided that there will be only one profile per user, if you want to have many profiles per user, then it won't be a `hasOne`. That's your decision.

Comment: Okay, so if i'm understanding this correctly, the foreign that is placed on the `profile` table is unique then?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. By Design.

Comment: Ahh okay, I feel stupid now... So if you placed the `public $hasOne = 'Profile';` on the User model this will make the foreign key unique? else if you put `$hasMany` then it would allow duplicate entries. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. You can try it by yourself. You can otherwise add the restriction in the table and that will generate an error.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark this as the answer. I making my own tests. I was over thinking it. Your answer and comments helped a lot, so thank you :).